# Gödel operations - finite sets

Tags: logic

How to prove that :

$\forall \alpha \in \omega : L(\alpha) $ is a finite set ?

I would like to apply Gödel's axioms/operations but I don't quite know how to go about it.

I marked $\omega = \aleph_0$ and I tried to show that when $\alpha < \omega$ then $L(\alpha)$ is a finite set.

$L(0)$ is the empty set and $L(\alpha + 1) = def(L(\alpha))$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Each element of $L_{n+1}$is a subset of $L_n$, so $|L_{n+1}|\leq2^{|L_n|}$.

Comment: Ok, so $|L_{n + 1}| \leq 2^{|L_n|} \leq 2^\alpha < \omega$ ?